# Gas cost of mapping operations

Tags: solidity, gas, mapping, gas-estimate

Suppose, your contract has something like

```
if (_balances[account] >= someNumber) {
    _balances[account] = _balances[account] - _balances[account]/10;
}
```

What is the gas cost of this operation? I guess, if the mapping `_balances` has a lot of entries, let's say millions of entries, then a search in such mappings could cost a lot of gas. Is it possible to estimate how much gas the above code consumes given the length of `_balances`? (Note that I'm not interested in the actual $ cost, but the amount of gas units regardless of gas price)

Comment: What type is `_balances`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the gas cost bellow. It should be the same regardless of how many users they are there. Mapping works a bit differently then list and it doesn't iterate through the multiple number of data like you would have to in case if a list. There is a reason why mappping data is not iterable.

[image]